# Java - TreeMap do not retrieves the key

Tags: java, key-value, treemap

I've topped with a problem I can not understand exactly what's happening here. 
I operate with a `TreeMap<Custom_class, TreeMap<Custom_class, Integer>>`

Here is the fragment of code:

```
TreeMap<Coordenada, Integer> helper_tree;
boolean newLine = false;

for (Linea l : this.lineas) {
  int helper = 0;
  newLine = true;
  Coordenada helper_co = null;

  for (Coordenada c : l.getNodosLinea()) {
    helper++;

    if (!c.getEsEstacion() && !c.getEsCruce()) continue;
    if (newLine) { map.putIfAbsent(c, new TreeMap<>()); helper_co = c; helper = 0; newLine = false; continue; }

    helper_tree = new TreeMap<>();
    helper_tree.put(helper_co, helper * 200);
    map.put(c, helper_tree);
    map.get(helper_co).put(c, helper * 200);
    helper_co = c;
    helper = 0;

  }
}
```

In the execution the highlighted line fails, getting 0 entry for a key:
[debug mode in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKC0F.jpg)

And this is `TreeMap` structure:
[TreeMap structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhzkS.jpg)

I dont understand why in fails at `.get(key)` when the key `Coordenada(12,2)` is present. All before works just fine.

`Coordenada` class

```
public class Coordenada implements Comparable<Coordenada>{
private int[] coordenada = new int[2];
private boolean esEstacion = false;
private boolean esCruce = false;

public Coordenada(int[] coordenada){
    this.coordenada[0] = coordenada[0];
    this.coordenada[1] = coordenada[1];
}

public void setCoordenada(int[] coordenada) {
    this.coordenada = coordenada;
}

public int[] getCoordenada() {
    return coordenada;
}

public void switchEstacion(){
    this.esEstacion = !this.esEstacion;
}

public void switchCruce() { this.esCruce = !this.esCruce; }

public boolean getEsEstacion() {
    return this.esEstacion;
}

public boolean getEsCruce() { return this.esCruce; }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object coord){
    Coordenada coordTemp = (Coordenada) coord;
    if (this.coordenada[0] != coordTemp.coordenada[0])
        return false;
    if (this.coordenada[1] != coordTemp.coordenada[1])
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Coordenada o) {
    if (this.coordenada[0] > o.coordenada[0] )
        return 1;
    if (this.coordenada[1] > o.coordenada[1] )
        return 1;
    if (this.coordenada[0] < o.coordenada[0])
        return -1;
    if (this.coordenada[1] < o.coordenada[1])
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + coordenada[0] + ", " + coordenada[1] + ")";
}
```

}

Inserts perfectly `Coordenada(12,2)` and modifies previous `helper_co = Coordenada(10,2)`
[debugger variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21SjM.jpg)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you override `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: In `Coordenada` class, will edit the main message.

Comment: To answer this question it's important to see the whole `Coordenada` class to rule out things like an error in the comparison function. (BTW, irrelevant to this question, but `Coordenada::equals` should return `false` instead of throwing an error if given an object that isn't a `Coordenada`.)

Comment: It retrieves `null` on `map.get(helper_co)` which is the previously introduced value in the map.

Will add the main message.

Comment: Your `compareTo` function has a bug. Consider `a = (12, 2)` and `b = (5, 5)`. `a.compareTo(b)` is `true` because the first `if`-clause matches. But also `b.compareTo(a)` is true because the first `if`-clause fails but the second clause matches. So `a > b` but also `b > a`. Fix this by comparing the `coordenada[0]` elements first, then only if they're equal comparing the `coordenada[1]` elements. This is likely why your program isn't working; binary search trees rely on consistent comparison to function.

Comment: It worked! But why does `compareTo` so important in `TreeMap`??
In docs I see that it's just impossible to have two SAME values. And `equals` is correct

Comment: `TreeMap` is an implementation of a binary search tree. For efficiency, binary search trees rely on being able to put items in order, and they use `compareTo` for that purpose. Read up on binary search trees for more information, but for practical purposes, know that whenever you implement `compareTo` in Java, you need to make sure that if `a.compareTo(b)` is 1 then `b.compareTo(a)` is -1, and if `a.compareTo(b)` is 0 then `b.compareTo(a)` is 0. If you don't do that, things like this will break in strange ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `compareTo` function

```
(0,1) compareTo (1,0) returns 1
(1,0) compareTo (0,1) returns 1
```

It's ambiguous.

Comment: But it works perfectly for all previous inserts. Only fails on the `Coordenada(12,2)` of the `Linea` class, all previous retrieves work for `Coordenada(10,2)` or `Coordenada(8,2)` while `helper_co` is the previous value.

Comment: @k-storm is `Coordenada(12,2)` the last (or first) insert?

Comment: no, the last is `(14,2)` which is `c` and it been introduced correctly too.

Comment: @k-storm I think you have a problem with the comparator.